# What happens if I create two class or id with the same name but different property, which one will execute and why?

Tags: css

What happens if I create two class or id with the same name but different property, which one will execute and why ?

I think in this case the class created first will give priority.

I just want to know.

Comment: Need a lot more information. Try creating a clear example.

Comment: By "different property" do you mean different property *Names*? Or do you mean same property Name, but different property *Values*?  The answer is different depending on this.

Comment: Purely going by what little information you have posted, it would be the one at the lowest position on a stylesheet due to cascading. Of course there's the position of the elements within the HTML to consider as well plus the specificity of the selectors.. I cannot believe anyone is bothering to answer such a lazy question. Please read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to show you:

```css
html {
  background-color: blue;
}

html {
  background-color: red;
}

html {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<html></html>
```

As you can see, the last duplicate rule defined is the one that is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more likely to be the second one, because generally computers will go by what value was assigned to a class or variable last. For example:

```js
var num = 1;
var num = 2;
alert(num);
//will alert “2”
```